# matplotlib inset_axis inset placement has tick labels overlapping parent axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, insets, multiple-axes

When I use `inset_axes` to place an inset in a figure, for small figure sizes, the tick labels for the inset will overlap the axes frame.  Is there a way to make the figure adjust to avoid this problem?

code:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(dd1["mag"].index, dd1["mag"], '.-',label="$\omega$")
ax1.plot(newindex,curvy1,'--', label="${0:.3f} \cdot I$".format(popt1[0]))
ax1.set_xlim((5e11, 5e13))
ax1.set_ylim((2e-7,.25e-4))

ax1_inset = inset_axes(ax1, width="40%", height="40%", loc=4)
ax1_inset.plot(dd1["mag"].index, (one - np.array(dd1["mag"]))/one)
ax1_inset.plot(dd1["mag"].index, map(lambda x: -.01, dd1["mag"].index), ':')
ax1_inset.set_xlim(5e11,5e13)
ax1_inset.set_ylim(-.1,.05)
ax1_inset.set_xscale("log")
```

with the matplotlibrc values:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = '4,3'

matplotlib.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_mathtext'] = 'True'
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = 'False'

matplotlib.rcParams['figure.subplot.left'] = .22
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.subplot.right'] = .95
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.subplot.bottom'] = .20
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.subplot.top'] = .90
```

[image: example figure]

Comment: There is not an automatic layout engine, you will have to fiddle with the placement, size, and font size to make it work.  IIRC `inset_axes` has a pad kwarg.

Comment: @tcaswell:  write up the specific kwarg for padding in an answer, and I'll accept it.  That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If that was enough for you to sort it out can you please write the answer up?  I don't recall the syntax of the top of my head, don't have the bandwidth to look it up / write it up today, and I don't really need the rep.

Comment: @tcaswell:  that is fine.  I thought I would offer it to you before I answered my own question.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

The kwarg "borderpad" appears to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you give a little more explanation?

Comment: adding ax_inset = inset_axes(...., borderpard=2.) increases the space between original axses and the inset

Comment: and/or decrease the width and height parameter